# Do Yodlee feed transaction descriptions change without new transaction being created?

Tags: yodlee

Customers have started to find that the transaction description field provided by Yodlee is changing, without the original / older transaction being removed and a new one being created in it's place.

Our expectation up to now is that if any changes take place, the old transaction is deleted and a new one is created, with a new internal `transaction_id` used by Yodlee. This is the system that is used for moving pending transactions to posted.

Is it now standard practice that merchant descriptions change frequently within the same transaction ID, or is this being done in error? Should we open a service request for the problem to be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee scrapes transactions from the Bank websites in each refresh for a specific duration- 30days, so if there are few transactions which got scraped and filed into Yodlee DB in previous refresh and now Bank has updated the description of those transaction while keeping rest of the information same. And say those are coming in current refresh also, then Yodlee will apply its logic and will update the description without changing anything else. But the chances when Bank Website does this is very rare.

If you are facing this kind of issue repeatedly/frequently then we suggest you to open a service request, with all the relevant information.

Note: The above scenario is in the case of Posted Transactions only.